# SharePoint interview questions

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Let's have a list of some good interview questions for SharePoint developers. Please provide one question per entry, and if possible, the answers.

Also, please feel free to suggest corrections if the provided answers are wrong.

I will go first:

Q: How does SharePoint store pages?

A: [How-to-locate-sharepoint-document-library-source-page-on-the-server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125805/how-to-locate-sharepoint-document-library-source-page-on-the-server#127138)

Answer (score 20):

Q. When running with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges (web context) what credentials are being used?

A. The App Pool Identity for the web application running SharePoint.

Comment: A: The identity of the current process. In a web context, this is the application pool identity. In a timer job, console application, etc. it will likely not be the app pool identity. Plan database permissions accordingly.

Comment: @dahlbyk - Thanks; I will clarify.  I never considered it being used in any other context.

Comment: Isn't this a bit too specific?  I like more open-ended questions that allow candidates to speak a bit more, such as the original author's question: How does SharePoint store pages?

Comment: To me it is much better to understand that a developer knows that RWEP is an absolute last resort. In most cases simply passing the System Account token to the SPSite constructor will accomplish what you need without needlessly elevating your network credentials.

Answer (score 15):

Q. When modifying a list item, what is the "main" difference between using SPListItem.Update() and SPListItem.SystemUpdate()?

A. Using SystemUpdate() will not create a new version and will also retain timestamps.

Comment: Also, it will List "System Account" as the Editor instead of the User Account, which has some other side-effects if you work with the SPListItem["Editor"] field.

Comment: I did not know that.  I thought it did more of a transparent update.

Comment: Bonus if the applicant knows about the "Page has been modified" error when updating a list item from, say, a web part (because of the new version being created).

Comment: SystemUpdate: also alerts is not sent, and modified by is not changed to system account.
Oh and versions are *not* preserved with the default method, you have to use the SystemUpdate(false) to do that (check UpdateInternal() method that SystemUpdate() calls)

Comment: SystemUpdate(true) will also retain the original Editor.

Answer (score 14):

Q: When should you dispose SPWeb and SPSite objects? And even more important, when not?

A: You should always dispose them if you created them yourself, but not otherwise. You should never dispose SPContext.Current.Web/Site and you should normally not dispose SPWeb if IsRootWeb is true. More tricky constructs are things along the line of SPList.ParentWeb.

Bonus Points if the candidate knows [Roger Lambs Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx).

Comment: Also dispose each web when iterating over SPWeb.Webs

Comment: Also dispose SPLimitedWebPartManager's SPWeb property (.web)

Answer (score 13):

Q: What is the difference between `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart`?

A: `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart` is provided in MOSS 2007 to provide backwards compatability with MOSS 2003 webparts.  In MOSS 2007, it is recommended to use `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` instead.

Comment: A few more things that I would like to add:
It is recommended to use ASP.NET webparts unless you need the following features:
Connections between web parts a Web Part zone
Cross page connections
data caching infrastructure that allows caching to the content database
 Client-side connections

Comment: Can you point to some documentation that says this?

Comment: http://www.pointsharepoint.com/2008/03/sharepoint-interview-questions.html

Answer (score 9):

sometimes I like to ask more open ended questions to get the prospect talking.

If I want to find out technical depth

Q: What bugs have you found in SharePoint? then Q: And what did you do to work around them?

Comment: Yeah outstanding question, anyone who knows MOSS, knows its held together with nuts and bolts, I guess another good interview question for MOSS is, do you have a strong stomach?

Comment: Agreed, a very good question as it'll allow a candidate to speak from experience or not as the case may be

Comment: this is a good question that in my experience is not suitable for a stressful situation such as an interview. People are less likely to remember these situations during an interview.

Comment: Q: What did You do to workaround need for SharePoint?

Comment: The worst to debug was when SharePoint calculated UTC date offsets twice. So annoying.

Answer (score 8):

Q: What is the performance impact of `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`?

A: `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` creates a new thread with the App Pool's credentials, blocking your current thread until it finishes.

[via [rexm](http://rexmorgan.net)]

Answer (score 7):

Q. If you have an ItemUpdated or ItemUpdating event receiver and it causes an update to the item, how do you prevent another ItemUpdated and ItemUpdating event from being fired during your update?

A. Before performing your update, call DisableEventFiring().  After update, call EnableEventFiring().

Answer (score 7):

Q. What is a site collection, why would you create a new site collection as opposed to a site?

A. Bit of a long answer, but they should know about site collection administration, quotas, seperation of assets, security model etc.

Dave Wollerman has a [good article](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/llowevad/archive/2007/06/25/site-collection-logical-architecture.aspx) on some of the whys and wherefores.

Answer (score 6):

Q: Describe the difference between a list and a library.

A: Lists are collections of metadata or columns, that can have attached documents.  Libraries are collections of documents (Excel, InfoPath, Word, etc.) plus optional metadata.

Edited per ktrauberman's feedback.

Comment: You can attach documents to a list item in a standard list, rather than a library.  The difference is that in a library, the file is the item, wheras in a list the file is just an extra "attachment".  You can also have multiple attachments to a list item.

Comment: I hate when I don't know the answer to my own question!!  :)

Comment: Also there is no check in/out functionality in list item.

Answer (score 6):

Q: (i) Describe the purpose of a content type and;
   (ii) give an example of where they might be used.

A: (i) A content type groups a set of list columns together so that they can be reused in the same way across sites.
   (ii) They could be used as a set of metadata columns that need to be applied to every document in a site collection.

Answer (score 6):

Q: Explain how SharePoint render its content.
A: Beyond scope here, but you can find some good information here: http://g-m-a-c.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-sharepoint-2007-renders-its-content.html

The applicant should at least get around the SharePoint's template rendering mechanism, and what's in the 12/TEMPLATE/CONTROLTEMPLATES/ and what it's used for with emphasis on DefaultTemplates.ascx. This is absolutely essential knowledge if you wish to do any kind of SharePoint customization.

Answer (score 6):

Q: Name at least two shared services available in MOSS 2007

A: Shared Services Providers in MOSS 2007 can provide the following shared services:

- User Profiles
- Audiences
- Personal Sites
- Search
- Excel Services
- Forms Services
- Business Data Catalog (Requires Enterprise Edition)

Comment: Nice - looking forward to trying it out

Comment: Hi Lars.  I thought Forms Services was just a farm feature, but have read in http://www.mosstest.net/Blog/SharePoint/DocLib/MOSS2007_MSW%EC%99%80%20MS%20Intranet%20%EC%86%8C%EA%B0%9C.pptx where MS InfoPath uses "the session state component of the SSP" (whatever that means).  Thoughts?

Comment: Hey Kirk, yes it is indeed confusing - I am also not 100% sure myself. But MS lists it as a SSP here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262914.aspx. But it is administered from Central Admin -> Application Management rather than from the SSP admin site.

Answer (score 6):

Q. What is the difference between MOSS & WSS

A. MOSS uses the Shared Service Provider for search, profile import, etc... (see the [answers posted by Lars Fastrup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205893/sharepoint-interview-questions/263148#263148) for a more complete list)

Comment: MOSS costs money, WSS is free with Windows Server.

Comment: Can you edit your post with a link to the Lars Fastrum answers?  (Or someone with editing privliges)

Answer (score 6):

Q: How would you programmatically retrieve a list item?

A: SPQuery and SPSiteDataQuery. Bonus points for knowledge of CrossListQueryCache, PortalSiteMapProvider. Negative points for use of foreach.

Answer (score 6):

Good ones. here are some really useful ones.
http://megasolutions.net/qs/Sharepoint_Portal_Interview_Questions.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Q: Why would you use a custom column?

A: It allows you to re-use the column in multiple libraries.  Particularly useful if you use a Choice type to restrict the user input to a predefined set of answers, and when that list of answers will likely change.

Comment: Surely that is a 'site column' a custom column would actually restrict you from doing exactly what you have said here.

Comment: Yes, what type of "custom column" is meant here? A custom field? Or a site column?

Answer (score 5):

Q. What base classes do event receivers inherit from?

A:

1. SPListEventReceiver, SPItemEventReciever, and SPWebEventReceiver inherit from the abstract base class SPEventReceiverBase.
2. SPWorkflowLibraryEventReceiver inherits from SPItemEventReceiver.
3. SPEmailEventReceiver inherits directly from System.Object.

Also see a collection of SharePoint Questions on: http://qmoss.blogspot.com/

Comment: Manish, stop advertising your blog in every answer.

Comment: What about SPFeatureReceiver which is used when you activate or de-activate your feature

Answer (score 4):

Q: What are the built in ways to backup a SharePoint install?

A: Through the central administration and the stsadm command

Q: (more advanced) You've created and deployed a Web Part, when you deploy to the server you get a page saying your Web Part couldn't be loaded, click here to go to the Web Part maintenance page, etc. to disable the web part.  What step(s) should you take to get a stack dump from your web part instead of that error page?

A: Go to the web.config file for your website and find the CallStack Attribute in the SafeControls element and set the value to true.

Comment: "Please provide one question per entry" probably wasn't a joke.

Answer (score 4):

Describe your experiences in applying custom branding to SharePoint 2007. What are some pitfalls to avoid? How do you deploy your custom branding to the farm?

Answer (score 4):

When/why should you/shouldn't you make direct changes or additions to the files in the 12 hive?

Answer (score 3):

Q. How would you create a Master/Detail page?

A. Creating a Content type inheriting from Folder Content Type for the master, and another Content type inheriting from Item and using them both on a List

Answer (score 3):

Describe the Business Data Catalog (BDC), and provide at least one of a tangible application for it.

Answer (score 2):

Q: What is a way of elevating SharePoint privileges without using RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

A: Pass the System Account User Token from the SPContext to the SPSite constructor.

A majority of times a developer can accomplish what they need using this method without needlessly elevating network credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather ask some open ended questions like 
Tell me something which you consider as an error that Microsoft has made in SharePoint?
Possible answers are...
For lookup columns you need to know the lookup field GUID in advance and you can’t easily provision a lookup field as a feature. 
MOSS does not have site level events such as an event for creating of lists. 
SharePoint designer is a crap and add unwanted stuff which increases the page size.
Lack of user group based trimming control as only permission based trimming is available by deafult (of cause you can create a custom security trimmer that does this)

Answer (score 1):

Q. What are the data types which are supported as Lookup column in SharePoint.

A. Only Single Line of Text and Calculated columns are supported as lookup columns.

Also I have consolidated some more questions on: http://qmoss.blogspot.com/